# zip files using CMake?

Tags: zip, cmake, cpack

**tl;dr version:**

Is it possible with CMake (>= 2.8) to generate zip files from some files and put the packed zip file in a specific location?

**longer version:**

I have a CMakeLists.txt that builds my project into a .exe file, and this exe file will read data from a zip file. The content to be packed in the zip file is in my git repository so that it can be edited, too. But, the program needs this data in a zip file. So it would be good if the CMake script could take the data, put it in a zip file, and place it next to the exe. I already heard of CPack, but I did not find any easy examples and am not sure if this is even the right tool for my task.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For CMake 3.18 or newer use the [ARCHIVE_CREATE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#archive-create) file command. It supports both the creation of zip and 7zip archives.

For example, if the current CMake source directory contains the file `testfile.txt` and the directory `testdir`, you can use the following CMake commands to create a zip file containing both items:

```
file(ARCHIVE_CREATE
    OUTPUT "archive.zip"
    PATHS 
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testfile.txt"
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testdir"
    FORMAT "zip")
```

For earlier versions of CMake (3.2 - 3.17) use the CMake [command-line mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#command-line-tool-mode) sub-command `tar` instead:

```
add_custom_target(create_zip COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar "cfv" "archive.zip" --format=zip
       "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testfile.txt"
       "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testdir")
```

For CMake versions earlier than 3.2, you can use the [jar](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jar.html) command that is part of a standard Java JRE installation.

```
find_package(Java)

execute_process(
    COMMAND
        "${Java_JAR_EXECUTABLE}" "cfM" "archive.zip" 
        "-C" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" "testfile.txt" 
        "-C" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" "testdir"
    RESULT_VARIABLE _result
)
```

The zip file will be generated in the current CMake binary dir (`CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`).

Comment: This method seems to create an empty zip file. However, seems like i'm able to create a populated archive by specifying the  "files-from=files.txt" option. Seems to fail with directories and files within directories

Comment: Ahh, just figured it out.. I'll explain below what I did to get this to work

Answer (score 12):

It's never late to show real answer:

```
function(create_zip output_file input_files working_dir)
    add_custom_command(
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar "cf" "${output_file}" --format=zip -- ${input_files}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY "${working_dir}"
        OUTPUT  "${output_file}"
        DEPENDS ${input_files}
        COMMENT "Zipping to ${output_file}."
    )
endfunction()
```

Use like

```
file(GLOB ZIP_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/zip/*")
create_zip("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/native_data.zip" "${ZIP_FILES}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/zip")
```

This will pack all files from `zip/` subdirectory into `native_data.zip` (in build directory). Then either include your archive (path will differ in different `CMakeLists.txt`!) as source file or add it as target:

```
add_custom_target("project-data" ALL DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/native_data.zip")
```

Install will not differ a lot from usual:

```
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/native_data.zip" DESTINATION ${DATADIR} RENAME "data000.zip") # Install our zip (as data000.zip)
```

Answer (score 7):

I assume you already have a zip-tool installed (WinZip or 7z, etc.). You could write a find_zip-tool script which will search for WinZip, or 7Z, etc...

Snippet for WinZip:

```
FIND_PROGRAM(ZIP_EXECUTABLE wzzip PATHS "$ENV{ProgramFiles}/WinZip")
IF(ZIP_EXECUTABLE)
  SET(ZIP_COMMAND "\"${ZIP_EXECUTABLE}\" -P \"<ARCHIVE>\" @<FILELIST>")
ENDIF(ZIP_EXECUTABLE)
```

Snippet for 7-zip:

```
  FIND_PROGRAM(ZIP_EXECUTABLE 7z PATHS "$ENV{ProgramFiles}/7-Zip") 
  IF(ZIP_EXECUTABLE)
    SET(ZIP_COMMAND "\"${ZIP_EXECUTABLE}\" a -tzip \"<ARCHIVE>\" @<FILELIST>")
  ENDIF(ZIP_EXECUTABLE)
```

Take a look at the file

```
<cmake-install-dir>\share\cmake-2.8\Modules\CPackZIP.cmake
```

it shows how CPack searches for a Zip_Executable and prepares some "useful" default flags.

After that, I would suggest to execute_process, similar to sakra's answer

Answer (score 7):

As of version 3.18, CMake now directly supports creating zip or archive files using the `file()` command with [`ARCHIVE_CREATE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/file.html#archive-create):

```
file(ARCHIVE_CREATE OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyData.zip
    PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/data
    FORMAT zip
)
```

Be sure to specify a **full** path for the `OUTPUT` zipped filename, or the file may not be generated. Also, the `PATHS` option accepts *files* or *directories* to be placed in the zip file, but it does **not** accept wildcards at the time of writing.

This command supports several archive formats and compression flavors. So, you can use the same command to create tarballs as well:

```
file(ARCHIVE_CREATE OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyData.tar.gz
    PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/data
    FORMAT gnutar
    COMPRESSION GZip
)
```

Comment: @yig I'm not sure what you mean. This command runs at the CMake *configure* stage, before any of your CMake targets are even built. If you want to zip CMake targets **after** they are built, you can try something like this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44810812/3987854) using the `POST_BUILD` option.

Comment: I was asking if this new 3.18 file(ARCHIVE_CREATE) functionality can be used in a target. Your answer clarifies that it cannot. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is the top search result for creating zip files with CMake, here is a CPack solution for completeness. The basic idea is that you make calls to `install()` and then tell it what to name the resulting zip file. It will be placed in the build directory, though there may be a way to change that. Then you can create the zip file with `make package` or `cpack`.

```
# Version 1: Subtractive
# Include everything in the project source directory.
# Put it at the top level of the zip via `DESTINATION .`
# Subtract things we don't want.
# The trailing slash after "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/" prevents
# an extra layer of directories.
install(DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/"
    DESTINATION .
    PATTERN ".git*" EXCLUDE
    PATTERN ".DS_Store" EXCLUDE
    PATTERN "examples" EXCLUDE
    PATTERN "docs" EXCLUDE
    PATTERN "README.md" EXCLUDE
)

# Version 2: Additive
# Include only the list of things we specify.
# Put it at the top level of the zip via `DESTINATION .`
# install(FILES
#     ${SRCS}
#     "Notes.txt"
#     DESTINATION .
# )

# Tell CPack to create a zip file.
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "ZIP")
# Tell CPack what to name the zip file. It will append `.zip`.
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}")
# Tell CPack not to put everything inside an enclosing directory.
set(CPACK_INCLUDE_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY OFF)
# Apparently this should be always on but isn't for backwards compatibility.
set(CPACK_VERBATIM_VARIABLES YES)
include(CPack)
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what I did was create custom target

```
add_custom_target(STAGE_FILES)
```

With this target I copy the files and directories to the `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`

```
add_custom_command( 
  TARGET STAGE_FILES 
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/video ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/video
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/data ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/data
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/strings_en.csv ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/strings_rules_en.csv ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar "cfv" "data.zip" --format=zip  --files-from=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/to_zip.txt
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove_directory ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/data
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E rename  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/data.zip ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/data
)
```

The important line

```
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar "cfv" "data.zip" --format=zip  --files-from=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/to_zip.txt
```

inside my

> to_zip.txt

I specify all the files I want to include in my zip

```
data/
video/
...
```

I can now execute the command

```
make STAGE_FILES
```

which will copy and zip everything i need