# Cmake zip folder but remove leading path

Tags: path, cmake, zip, filepath

I would like to zip folder in my project from *CMake*. For that I use following code snippet:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND (
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    ARGS -E tar cvf ${ZIP_OUT_DIR}/my_archive.zip --format=zip -- ${FOLDER_TO_ZIP}/another_folder/
)
```

The problem with this code is that the files after unzipping contain path component (`../../my_file.txt` in my case). I tried to use `tar cvf -C ${FOLDER_TO_ZIP}/another_folder` but unfortunatelly *CMake* doesn't accept this option.

How can I get rid of leading path from zip archive when using *CMake* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paths are relative to the working directory. So you just need to specify the `WORKING_DIRECTORY`:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar cvf ${ZIP_OUT_DIR}/my_archive.zip --format=zip -- .
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${FOLDER_TO_ZIP}/another_folder
)
```

Comment: That solution runs well, if you want to archive files only in that directory. But how to do it, if I need files from different directories to be archived? I could add a second custom command, but I would like to avoid that. Any idea?

Comment: I didn't see any clever solution for a single call to tar command, but of course it is possible to execute several commands in one `add_custom_command` similar as it is done in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050997/zip-files-using-cmake.